# Run a script wrapper instead of the real application in KDE

Tags: debian, kde

I am trying to limit the time my kids are playing Minecraft on our home PC (Debian 11 Bullseye). This is a family PC, used occassionally by everyone, so we are always logged in using a single user account.

To mitigate the issue, I wrote a small bash script that checks the current time, and if is outside of bounds then it shows a message box instead of starting the game. But now I stuggle how to swap the command configured for the icons in KDE. When I changed Exec in `/usr/share/applications/minecraft-launcher.desktop` it doesn't seem to have any effect, the game is executed without the script. How can I edit the configuration?

EDIT
My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "Starting Minecraft"
currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ "$currenttime" > "21:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "12:30" ]]; then
  logger 'Attempting to start Minecraft ouside of allowed hours'
  notify-send 'Minecraft' 'Minecraft is disabled at this time. System administrator has been notified.'
else
  minecraft-launcher
fi
```

I managed to make it work inside a desktop icon by putting '
bash /usr/bin/minecraft-starter' as the command. However, *it still does not work with the launcher in the main KDE menu*. Whatever I do, the the system executes the original launcher.

Comment: If you right click on your application launcher (start menu) in KDE there should be an `Edit Applications...` button. Would that work?

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure what to configure there to make it work...

Comment: If you select Minecraft inside KDE Menu Editor, there should be a `Program:` field, that points to the Minecraft binary. You need to replace that path with the location of your script.

Comment: I get `Warning: execve: Exec format error`, and the script doesn't actually execute.

Answer (score 0):

The intended solution - find all launchers, on a desktop, in the menu, or maybe kids copied it into some folder, away from parent's eyes? :) and change the launcher's command to your script.

Another solution, go to where the actual start binary is, and rename it to something (for example `mv minecraft craftmine`). Take you script, change the game starting binary accordingly. Put your script into the old place of the game.

This solution will allow you to keep desktop/menu launchers as is, and even running `minecraft` in the terminal will go to your script.

Just three problems:

- each time you update the game - your script would be overwritten and you would have to repeat substitution. Each time on each update.
- The game starting binary (not sure about `minecraft` though) can check its name on start and/or use it for something - so after renaming binary, make sure it still works.
- A kid can solve this riddle and just start the `craftmine` bypassing your script :)

Comment: Whatever hack I try, I cannot figure out how to run a script from these launchers. I get `Warning: execve: Exec format error` and the script actually doesn't execute.

Comment: @Grzenio Show your wrapper script, add it to the original post. Make sure your script is executable and you can run it successfully from a terminal

Comment: Added more information to the question, thanks!